# Pubnub installation on Onion omega 2 plus freezes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pubnub

I am unable to install the python pubnub SDK on my Onion Omega 2 plus board. The installation always freezes at the following stage:

```
root@Omega-E5A5:/# pip3 install pubnub
Collecting pubnub
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/a4/321d50db8786e19e41be43da22fe38a03d5fc0560d9b815a8b5e11ea068e/pubnub-4.0.13.tar.gz
Collecting pycryptodomex>=3.3 (from pubnub)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/c4/21d55c2bf30995847406cb1a737d4ae5e19615eca39c9258f0548b5656f1/pycryptodomex-3.6.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=2.4 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pubnub)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.10 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pubnub)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.4->pubnub)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.4->pubnub)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.4->pubnub)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests>=2.4->pubnub)
Installing collected packages: pycryptodomex, pubnub
  Running setup.py install for pycryptodomex ... /
```

I tried installing the pycryptodomex library manually with no success, still had the same problem. It freezes after a certain point during setup.py run.

Comment: Try adding the `--verbose` option to get more useful logging output.

Answer (score 2):

1. I was able to install PubNub on my Mac.

   - 'pip install pubnub'
2. ENV

   - what's your Python version?
     python v3 got 'venv' by default,
   - have you tried installing 'pubnub' under a 'venv'?

Feel free to contact PubNub's support team, they are very helpful :)

Comment: Pubnub works for me on my windows pc and raspberry pi too. But I am unable to get it going on the onion omega 2 plus board. My python version is 3.6

Comment: There is a guide for using Python and PubNub without the SDK, maybe this will help for your use case? https://www.pubnub.com/blog/iot-publish-and-subscribe-without-and-sdk-using-rest-api/